# Ubuntu thinks matplotlib is not responding when running with ion()

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, matplotlib-animation, matplotlib-ion

I want a plot updates in real-time, updating once on each run of a loop that takes a bit of time to run. The code works, but I'm getting a lot of popups saying Visual Studio Code is not responding between updates (during the sleep in the code below), which gets annoying.

Minimal reproduction below, it starts giving popups when the sleep gets to over 7 seconds.

Popup text: "Visual Studio Code" is not responding. You may choose to wait a short while for it to continue or force the application to quit entirely.

**How can I prevent these popups?**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

x = []
y = []
plt.ion()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = ax.plot(x, y)[0]
for i in range(100):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(i**2)
    p.set_xdata(x)
    p.set_ydata(y)

    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()

    time.sleep(i) # Code that takes a while goes here
```

Comment: "_popups saying Visual Studio Code is not responding between updates_"please add the exact message in those popups in a blockquote for searchability purposes.

Comment: I did not encounter the issue you mentioned when using vscode version 1.78.0. Please try to update vscode.

Comment: I still run into this issue after updating vscode. I am running version 1.80.1 on ubuntu.